# how to set seperator prefrence header for mac while creating csv with php

Tags: php, csv

I am generating a csv file with php.

It works fine in windows, linux.  But in  mac (excel) it comes in a messed way.

All data comes in one column  and does not get seperated by commas.

I was wondering if there is any way to pass headers for mac excel so it identifies the seperator (comma) by default.

Here are the header that I been using.

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
//header('Content-type: application/ms-excel');
//header("Content-Type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".xls");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".xls");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".strlen($csv_output));
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

Thanks
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

When you use,

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".xls");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".xls");
```

You are creating an Excel file and inserting CSV data in it. 
You can try using this as your header:

```
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
```